# Matlab returning matrix with value of element's rank in descending order

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

What is the easiest way to return a matrix in Matlab with the value of their element's rank when sorted in descending order?

For example, if I have the matrix

- `[2 43 46 9; 78 3 14 6]`

and want to sort the rows, I want to return

- `[4 2 1 3; 1 4 2 3]`,

since in the first column, 2 is the 4th largest, 43 is the 2nd largest, 46 is the largest, 9 is the 3rd largest etc...

Comment: To clarify, I don't want the indices, which can be done using Matlab's sort function.

Comment: If I wanted the indices, wouldn't it return [3 2 4 1;1 3 4 2]?

Comment: oh never mind.  I misunderstood your question.  I see what you want.

Comment: Found a duplicate.  Good luck!

Comment: Tried to answer this but the question is now closed, so now my answer has a funky format- sorry.  The following code will first sort your matrix in descending order, then identify the order in which its listed in matrix x1: 

   'x = [2 43 46 9];
    y = sort(x,'descend');
    
    for i = 1:length(x);
        x1(i) = find(y==x(i));
    end'

where `x1 = [4 2 1 3]`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid loops. Also, the suggested page deals only with vectors, but I want to sort each row independently, as the unique function seems to vectorize the matrix. If I can't find a solution with only Matlab functions, then I will just do it your way, thanks.